# Trying to improve msql query output

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue creating a query.  The following is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT sitedata.sitecode       Site, 
       projectdata.startdate   Start, 
       projectdata.enddate     End, 
       resourcedata.firstname  PM_Name, 
       resourcedata.firstname  Lead_Name, 
       rresourcedata.firstname Other_Name 
FROM   projectdata 
       JOIN sitedata 
         ON projectdata.siteid = sitedata.id 
       JOIN resourcedata 
         ON projectdata.pmid = resourcedata.id 
             OR projectdata.leadid = resourcedata.id 
             OR projectdata.otherid = resourcedata.id 
WHERE  startdate = '03/06/2013'
```

The output currently from my query is as follows:

```
Site   PM_Name   Lead_Name   Other_Name   
ST1    Joe       Joe         Joe
ST1    Jim       Jim         Jim
ST1    Bill      Bill        Bill
ST2    Lee       Lee         Lee
ST2    Jim       Jim         Jim
ST2    Bill      Bill        Bill
```

Below is the output I am trying to get:

```
Site   PM_Name   Lead_Name    Other_Name   
ST1    Jim       Joe          Bill
ST2    Bill      Lee          Jim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is join to you resources table 3 times for each respective name you are looking for...

```
SELECT 
      sitedata.sitecode       Site, 
      projectdata.startdate   Start, 
      projectdata.enddate     End, 
      PM.firstname  PM_Name, 
      LEAD.firstname  Lead_Name, 
      OTHER.firstname Other_Name 
   FROM   
      projectdata 
         JOIN sitedata 
            ON projectdata.siteid = sitedata.id 
         JOIN resourcedata as PM
            ON projectdata.pmid = PM.id 
         JOIN resourcedata LEAD
            ON projectdata.leadid = LEAD.id 
         JOIN resourcedata OTHER
            ON projectdata.otherid = OTHER.id 
   WHERE  
      startdate = '03/06/2013'
```

Comment: Are you saying that I need to create the following tables/field rather than using resourcedata.firstname?
PM.firstname  PM_Name, 
LEAD.firstname  Lead_Name, 
OTHER.firstname Other_Name

Comment: nm me...had a misplaced comment causing an error...seems to be working!

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 separate JOINS:

```
SELECT sitedata.sitecode       Site, 
       projectdata.startdate   Start, 
       projectdata.enddate     End, 
       pm.firstname  PM_Name, 
       ld.firstname  Lead_Name, 
       on.firstname Other_Name 
FROM   projectdata 
       JOIN sitedata ON projectdata.siteid = sitedata.id 
       LEFT JOIN resourcedata pm ON projectdata.pmid = resourcedata.id 
       LEFT JOIN resourcedata ld ON projectdata.leadid = resourcedata.id 
       LEFT JOIN resourcedata on ON projectdata.otherid = resourcedata.id 
WHERE  startdate = '03/06/2013'
```

I used LEFT JOINs in case some of the roles are not assigned (NULL), if you're sure this is not the case you can continue using INNER JOINs.